# VB.NET Databinding from 2 Tables

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding

I have the following structure

```
|-Table 1
|--PK IDT1
|--Name field
|-Table 2
|--PK ID
|--FK IDT1
|--Name field
```

I want to bind Table 1 to combobox1 and Table 2 to combobox2 so as when someone selects a value in combobox1, combobox2 populates with only the rows with the FK IDT1 value from combobox1. Is this possible with databinding or do I have to code it?

Comment: Is this about WinForms, WPF or ASP.Net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the `FORM_LOAD` of your application just populate only `ComboBox1`. this psuedocode may help you:

ON FORM_LOAD of your Application:

```
      Bind ComboBox1
      SET DISPLAY MEMBER Property of BomboBox1 to field
      SET VALUE MEMBER Property of ComboBox1 to IDT1
      Clear ComboBox1 current Text
```

On the **SelectionChangeCommitted** of your `ComboBox1`

```
      Bind ComboBox2 using the following Query:
           SELECT ID, field FROM Table2 WHERE IDT1 = ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString
      SET DISPLAY MEMBER Property of ComboBox2 to field
      SET VALUE MEMBER Property of ComboBox2 to IDT
```

The **SelectedIndexChanged** event is *raised* every time the SelectedIndex property value changes. If your ComboBox is initially empty then its SelectedIndex is -1. When you bind data to it the first item is selected by default and the SelectedIndex changes to 0. You are then explicitly setting the SelectedIndex to -1 again.

If you're only interested in knowing when the user makes a selection then handle the **SelectionChangeCommitted** event instead.