# VB.NET Query Datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a DataTable

```
|------------|
| id | x | y |
|------------|
|  1 | 1 | 1 |
|  2 | 1 | 2 |
|  3 | 2 | 1 |
|  4 | 2 | 2 |
|------------|
```

I would like to filter this DataTable by value of x to come up with a new DataTable

```
if x = 1
|------------|
| id | x | y |
|------------|
|  1 | 1 | 1 |
|  2 | 1 | 2 |
|------------|

or x = 2 
|------------|
| id | x | y |
|------------|
|  3 | 2 | 1 |
|  4 | 2 | 2 |
|------------|
```

Queries of populated datasets and datatables still baffle me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: kindly check my answer to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749526/vb-net-databinding-from-2-tables

Comment: kindly check my answer to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749526/vb-net-databinding-from-2-tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first [filter the data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx):

```
MyTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "x = 1"
```

Then you [copy the view to a new table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73kk32zz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
Dim MyNewTable As DataTable = Mytable.DefaultView.ToTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a new DataTable and clone the original one to bring over the schema and constraints. Then filter the rows and add it to the new DataTable.

```
Dim newDT As DataTable = oldDT.Clone()

Dim filter As string = "x = 1"; 

//get the rows from the that have been filtered
DataRow[] filteredRows = oldDT.Select(filter);

//add the rows to the new datatable
For Each dr As DataRow In filteredRows
    newDT.ImportRow(dr)
Next
```